# Gradle exclude classes from aar

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Im using lib Gson in my dependecies and im import a .aar with some classes from Gson that are imported to a project.
When i build my project i keep getting duplicated classes, bcz its on my dependency and aar classes.

How i can exclude gson classes from aar?

I have been trying with:

- exclude group: I think this is not work since is not a dependency from aar, but classes inside.
- transitive true, same reason as before

Can i do it? or should i get other .aar with gson as dependecy?

Comment: Are you adding `gson` as a gradle dependency or are you literally copying source files from `gson` into your project? if you're doing the latter, remove these files and add `gson` as a dependency. As long as you use the same version across all libraries you shouldn't have a problem. If you're exporting them as aar and including them again, make sure you add the required dependencies of the library to your root project. If anything else, show us your gradle dependencies

Comment: Copying source files from gson and i cant add it as dependecy because i dont have control of it, so i must have to use it like this way.
aar with gson source code and my project using gson dependecy.

Comment: That's written a bit confusingly... Can you list the dependencies in question and list how you add them to your project? (gradle, aar, source code copy). Also if you have any aar, extract it and check if any `gson` namespaces are within or if they are declared as a dependency in a pom file

Comment: If I'm reading correctly and gson is packaged into the aar and you don't have access to the source-code of the aar you'd have to somehow find a way to remove the gson parts within the aar, provide your own gson as a dependency and hope that the aar works with that version

Comment: Thats what im asking if i can do it :). I cant change aar inside, so i have to exclude classes from aar on compile(?) and use mine

Answer (score 0):

Usually .aar includes with .pom file which includes all dependency of "aar library" use.

If you are creating own library and use it in another application follow refer the link below.
https://medium.com/swlh/android-library-kotlin-creation-access-deploy-problems-fixes-everything-you-want-to-c1a1701f0e8f

Or

Try this following

```
implementation(name: '××××××× aar package', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude module: 'gson'
}
```

Let me know if this helpfull

Comment: Sorry but gson was not as pom dependecy but source code copy

Answer (score 0):

1. Download & Unzip  the original .aar library file
2. Remove the specific class file you want to exclude from the library

```bash
unzip original_lib.aar -d out/
cd out/
zip -d classes.jar "com/something/ClassToBeRemoved.class"
jar cvf ../my_new_lib.aar
```

Now you have a new AAR library file named `my_new_lib.aar`, which excludes the specified class file.

You can include local .aar library in Gradle using:

```
implementation files('aar/my_new_lib.aar')
```

Remember to replace "com/something/ClassToBeRemoved.class" with the actual path and name of the class file you want to exclude. Also, ensure that you are in the correct directory when executing these commands.

This approach allows you to manually remove **specific class** files from an AAR library.